# Django-taggit inserting

Tags: django, django-taggit

My model defines one field like

```
keywords = TaggableManager(_('Keywords'), blank=True)
```

From view I need to use get_or_create in a for

```
***
with transaction.commit_on_success():
    # Inserting obj_parsed
    defaults = {
        'owner': user,
        'title': obj.title,
        'abstract': obj.abstract,
        #'keywords': [kw for kw in obj.keywords],
        'url': obj.url,
    }

    obj_instance, created = Obj.objects.get_or_create(
                                title=obj.title, defaults=defaults)
    if not created:        
        result['error'] = _('URL already in the repository') 
        return result
```

obj.keywords is a list (it can be empty) but get_or_create gives me the error "TypeError: 'keywords' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

How can I solve this?

I don't want to do

```
mymodel = Obj(**defaults)
mymodel.save()
mymodel.keywords.add([kw for kw in obj.keywords])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had a similar problem and looked into the [taggit tests](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/develop/tests/tests.py). The only thing I got working is adding the tags after creation like so:

```
defaults = {
    'owner': user,
    'title': obj.title,
    'abstract': obj.abstract,
    'url': obj.url,
}
obj_instance, created = Obj.objects.get_or_create(title=obj.title, defaults=defaults)
obj_instance.add(*obj.keywords)
```